# Set default values in nhibernate-mapping

Tags: .net, mysql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, default

I am trying to put a default value in a mapping. When I run it says "default" not declared.

my code is

```
<property name="retrycount" column="retrycount" type="Int32" default="0" />
```

Is this support for nhibernate

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

it is supported:

```
<property name="retrycount" type="Int32">
  <column name="retrycount" default="0"/>
</property>
```

Comment: Can this be done based on logic? Specifically, based on another property?

Comment: @JustinMorgan depends on the capabilities of the rdbms. the default is just appended to the create column string e.g. `columnname NOT NULL DEFAULT <your string here>`